# С++ стек и очереди

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Нужно написать программу на С++ (мы сейчас проходим стек и очереди), а что нужно получить и вывести в результате работы программы мне не понятно. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, что в этой программе с чего начать и что получить? Вот условие: "Есть министерство из N чиновников, где N натуральное число. У каждого из чиновников могут быть как подчиненные, так и начальники, причем справедливы правила: подчиненные моего подчиненного мои подчиненные, начальники моего начальника - мои начальники, мой начальник не есть мой подчиненный, у каждого чиновника не более одного непосредственного начальника."

Comment: Условие явно неполное. Пока понятно, что иерархия - дерево. Но что с ним делать - не спрашивается

Answer (score 0):

В задаче вам необходимо реализовать структуру данных, которая позволяет хранить информацию о чиновниках в описанном формате. Судя по описанию предполагается использовать древовидную структуру хранения. Я советую почитать вам про деревья и графы. Число N в данном контексте - это количество вершин дерева.